# C++ numerical integration library

Tags: library, c++, numerical-analysis

Does anybody know a c++ library for numerical integration of samples (data points (x,y)), like scipy integrate.simps?
I know it's not hard to implement by myself (in fact I already did), but I need to do this very often for large data sets, that's why I am looking for a maybe faster library implementation.
I already checked boost and gsl, but didn't find anything!

Thanks and cheers

Comment: Why is it important to you that the library be in C++? Can't you use just any library (i.e. a .so or a .dll shared library)? Maybe this is also the reason why you haven't found one, this doesn't seem something particularly language-specific.

Comment: Of course, any library is fine, as long as it's compatible with my code

Comment: how about making your code compatible with a library ?

Comment: :-) .. also ok, but as I wrote below, writing an interpolating function to get a continuous function doesn't help, since it would slow down the calculation. Thus, I am looking for a library, function, which can handle an array, vector, whatever, with a fixed number of points!

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the relatively popular [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) (GSL), which is by the way what GCC uses internally (although not the numerical integration part).

It has a pretty long [manual section](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Numerical-Integration.html#Numerical-Integration) on numeric integration, describing:

- QNG non-adaptive Gauss-Kronrod integration
- QAG adaptive integration

  - with singularities
  - with known singular points
  - on infinite intervals:
  - for Cauchy principal values:
  - for singular functions
- adaptive integration

  - for oscillatory functions
  - for Fourier integrals
- CQUAD doubly-adaptive integration
- Fixed order Gauss-Legendre integration

And most/all of these seem to be sample-based (rather than integrating using some symbolic representation).

It's written in C, but it seems you're willing to accept that.

Also, Wikipedia has a [long list of numerical libraries in various languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries), including C and C++. I haven't much experience with numerical work in C or C++ (just a bit in MatLab), so I haven't tried any, but - you should.

If you do so, consider answering your own question and reporting which libraries fit your requirement (basically) and which you've chosen.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but as far as I understand it, all the GSL numerical integration algorithms need a function (const gsl_function * f) as input. Of course I could interpolate my data points to get a continous function, but this would even slow down my calculations. None of these algorithms accept an array, or vector, of discrete points as input.